# TableView inside cell in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

I have an collectionView with "Chat like" layout.

This is how I "Send messages" in chat:

```
private func sendMessage(message: ChatMessage) {
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] in
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self?.messages.count ?? 0, section: 0)
            self?.messages.append(message)
            self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
        }) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Also I have an cell for this collectionView with TableView inside to represent possible answers to the question. For that tableView estimatedRowHeight == 44, isScrollEnabled = false and rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension. This is how I calculate size of cell:

```
    @discardableResult
    func layout() -> CGFloat {
        let tableViewSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: ChatCellConstants.textMaxSize, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        let titleSize = titleLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: ChatCellConstants.textMaxSize, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        let contentWidth = max(tableViewSize.width, titleSize.width)
        let tableViewHeight = answers.reduce(0) { partialResult, data in
            return partialResult + cell.set(text: data.title, isSelected: false, animated: false).layoutHeight()
        }
        
        if isMyMessage {
            tableView.layout(
                right: right - ChatCellConstants.textHOffset,
                top: titleLabel.bottom + ChatCellConstants.standartOffset,
                width: contentWidth,
                height: tableViewHeight
            )
            chatBubleView.backgroundColor = AppTheme.shared.colors.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        } else {
            tableView.layout(
                top: titleLabel.bottom + ChatCellConstants.standartOffset,
                left: left,
                width: contentWidth,
                fitHeight: tableViewHeight
            )
            chatBubleView.backgroundColor = AppTheme.shared.colors.cian.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        }
        titleLabel.layout(left: tableView.left, right: tableView.right, top: ChatCellConstants.standartOffset, height: titleSize.height)
        checkButton.layout(left: tableView.left, right: tableView.right, top: tableView.bottom + ChatCellConstants.standartOffset, height: 48)

        chatBubleView.layout(
            left: tableView.left - ChatCellConstants.standartOffset,
            right: tableView.right + ChatCellConstants.standartOffset,
            top: titleLabel.top - ChatCellConstants.standartOffset,
            bottom: checkButton.bottom + ChatCellConstants.standartOffset
        )
        return chatBubleView.bottom
    }
```

The problem is as follows: when the text of the answer options to a question is too large, the tableView turns out to be cropped and all the necessary cells are not displayed in it. They begin to be displayed if you scroll this cell off the screen and then return to it again.

I expect that the tableView will be displayed in full size immediately when the corresponding cell appears in the collectionView.
[image]

Comment: Can we maybe get some screenshots?

Comment: @VisalRajapakse oops, edited

Comment: @PavelPud - as a general rule, nested table views are not a great approach, and very often produce unexpected - and difficult to fix - problems. *"... with TableView inside to represent possible answers ..."* -- you will almost certainly be better off using something like a `UIStackView` instead of a table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto layout to calculate UITableView height.
Here is a example:

```
//Create a subclass of UITableView
class SizebleTableView: UITableView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        // This way the width is defined by the frame
        // And height value is taken from content size of
        CGSize(width: frame.width, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Then wherever you update the table you should call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`:

```
@IBAction private func addItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
    items.append("Aditional item #\(items.count + 1)")
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

I think you need to disable scroll, bounce and scroll indicators so it looks like normal view.

Here is the result:
[TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2zlE.gif)